# When can I modify a page that was GIFT'd to vmsplice?

Tags: linux, pipe, memory, ram

When `vmsplice(4)` is used with `SPLICE_F_GIFT` it is promised that my process won't modify the underlying page(s) I gift. The normal work flow I'm informed is:

```
/*pseudo code don't kill me*/
void* page = memmap();
vmsplice(page, SPLICE_F_GIFT);
free(page);
```

But this requires me to invalidate my TLB every time I gift a page. Which nicely negates any performance gain I get from not copying the data.

So how can I know the kernel is *done* with my page? As I can simply *not* free the page right?

I'm assuming for a use case like:

```
vmsplice -> pipe -> splice -> tcpsocket
```

I would wait for a response, at which point the kernel will flush its `SEND` buffer and my page will be mine again?

Answer (score 0):

> So how can I know the kernel is done with my page? As I can simply not free the page right?

[a gift to the kernel. The application may not modify this memory **ever**, otherwise the page cache and on-disk data may differ.](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/vmsplice.2.html)

> vmsplice -> pipe -> splice -> tcpsocket
>
> I would wait for a response, at which point the kernel will flush its SEND buffer and my page will be mine again?

no

Wait until a response *which in the protocol you use, acknowledges that all the gifted pages have been received*.  Then you will know that the kernel *has* flushed the send buffer, of all the gifted pages.

(Btw I wouldn't assume the content of the pages survives.  I imagine it could be encrypted in-place for IPSec).

<del>Apparently it's also possible to retrieve "the amount of unsent data in the socket send queue", so that's another way to do it.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6421771/vmsplice-and-tcp  (of course you don't have to wait for it to fall to 0 as per this link, you could re-use each page as it becomes safe).  It requires polling in the case where you're not filling the kernel send queue.  (When you are, you just re-check at the same time <del>select()</del> epoll() tells you there's more space to write data).</del>

Answer (score 0):

The intended usage is to vmsplice gifting mmaped pages, you can't change those after vmsplice, but you can munmap them.